# Free memory again [Unix]

Tags: unix, memory, memory-management

I executed a C++ program on a huge amount of data and it ran into an infinite loop. I just quit the terminal. But looking at the processes now shows that there is still the process which allocates 12GB RAM.

Do I have to kill the process manually to free the memory again or does the system free it itself after a certain time?

Comment: if the process is still running, then no, the memory won't be freed. the OS can't just randomly decide to free a processe's memory. that'd SERIOUSLY screw up the process. the os can choose to out-of-memory KILL a process, but it wouldn't just reach in and yank memory away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I should do $ kill PID ?

Comment: @cruxi What does `ps- A` show? Do you have a zombie process?

Comment: The OS *can* choose to swap some memory (usually to disk) if it's running out. But it can't just yank it away from a process that's using it (obviously, if it has just allocated it but never written to it, then there are more options; but then the OS probably wouldn't have actually allocated physical memory for it anyway - just set away some virtual address space).

Answer (score 0):

> So I should do $ kill PID ?

Yes, if you don't want a program to run in an infinite loop, you should kill it, not only to free memory, but also to not waste CPU time.